# jquery tooltips code having to do it everytime

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

Every plugin or code I find for html tooltips have one issue that I need a workaround, they always have the content that needs to be displayed near the trigger and I dont want that, I want to have a list with all the options that can be triggered and then only call whatever I want at that time.

Why do I want this? I want everytime I paste one image that it shows a tooltip for that image and without needing to have the `<span>` with all the info that the tooltip will show.

I hope I'm clear :\

Edit: Yes, I tried to put the tooltip  (or div) outside the trigger and it doesnt work.

Edit2:

```
<a href="#" class="tip_trigger">Your Link Key Word <span class="tip">This will show up in the tooltip</span></a>
```

Most tooltips work like above, in a way or another, either using the  content as the tooltip or title. What I want is something like this for the example above.

All possible tooltips separated:

```
<span class="tip">This will show up in the tooltip</span>
```

And then in the code:

```
<a href="#" class="trigger_tip">Your Link Key Word</a>
```

Something like this. I hope im clear now

What I need is something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/MMcHs/1/

But somehow on worldpress the html isnt being loaded well

Comment: Perhaps you should show an example of what you want to do.

Comment: So, you want to have a list of tool-tip information on the page, somewhere not-near the associated element, and somehow call that when the associated element is hovered-over?

Comment: Isn't this how [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/) works? The tooltip content is in the options to the method call, not in the element.

Comment: Yes David Thomas, and sorry I cant be more clear. Ill try to edit with an example.

Comment: Do you want to have the tip text stored somewhere else in the DOM?

Comment: yes. and btw qTip only uses simple text I think I want a html span or div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the tooltips like you have mentioned in your example, and use jquery to dynamically add the titles needed by jquery ui..

http://jsfiddle.net/MMcHs/

Taking the jquery ui tooltip example..

HTML

```
<p><a href="#" id="anchor_tip">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
<a href="http://themeroller.com" id="anchor_tip2">ThemeRoller</a>
will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p>
    <label for="age">Your age:</label>
    <input id="age" />
</p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
<div class="myToolTip" data-tip-id="#anchor_tip">
     <h1>Heading 1 in the tooltip</h1>

    <p>That's what this widget is</p>
</div>
<div class="myToolTip" data-tip-id="#anchor_tip2">ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder application</div>
<div class="myToolTip" data-tip-id="#age">We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $(".myToolTip").each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('data-tip-id')).attr('title', $(this).html());
    });
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

CSS

```
  label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 5em;
  }
  .myToolTip {
      display: none;
  }
```

Comment: does it work from another document or with includes? (Having all possible tooltips on another file etc)

Comment: the tooltips need to be present in the DOM when you call `$(document).tooltop();` .. Where do you want to store the tooltips?

Comment: Im just thinking, I have for instance 60 tooltips. that could be or not invoqued. so I was wondering if I could store them in another document

Comment: What determines whether they are invoked?  You should probably only display the tooltips you want invoked on any given page load

Comment: for instance, on the code above I could call what I need with the id right? so that determines if the tooltip is invoqued or not

Comment: can you add some code to a jsfiddle and link it here?  that would be easier

Comment: I was trying to use the code above with the ideia i had because it might work since the tooltips are not in the same area code of the invoquer

Comment: the above code was working fine, until I tried to set up some code in a div that includes tables and such :| now the tooltip its just code of the table

Comment: it works on http://jsfiddle.net/MMcHs/1/ but doesnt work on my website... any ideia why?

Comment: dawnsource.com i've tried the code everywhere in everyplace. its a worldpress website

Comment: First thing you should do is clean up the js errors.. It will probably work after that http://www.anony.ws/i/2013/06/13/EbvKw.jpg

Comment: F12 in Chrome, then click Console tab.. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Yeah i found where to. but that are some plugins :x

Comment: http://www.dawnsource.com/amarynth/ go here, press recomended items and go through tooltip. it shows table code :X

Comment: why is it printing this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'  ?

Comment: looking at your source, you aren't including the tooltip js.  I would remove all jquery ui references and add <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: that didnt work on slider after :X using this: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
the tooltip js is being included, its on <?php include 'tooltips.php'?>

Comment: i've changed everything, keep getting this Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip' on the tooltip script

Comment: I really dont get whats wrong damn :| edit: apparently only works on fiddle. coppied all code here: http://www.dawnsource.com/work/teste2.php

Comment: i sent a message via the contact form on your site.. Since you dont have enough rep, you can't chat, and this isnt the place to debug the issue

Comment: mail me directly: cristiano_marques@live.com please